# Creating Many-2-Many reference with EF

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, poco

In my current project (which is really small) i have 3 tables/**POCO entities** which i would like to manipulate using EF.

The Tables are:

1. *Status* (contains status details)
2. *StatusStatusType* (which is needed because of the many-2-many relationship)
3. *StatusType* (A table which is used to group statuses by type)

I now want to create a new Status in the database and user code like you see below

```
//Create new status (POCO) entity
var newStatus = new Status {
    StatusId = status.Id,
    UserId = user.Id,
    Text = status.text,
    CreateDate = DateTime.Now
};

// Persist need status to database
using (var db = new demoEntities())
{
    db.Statuses.AddObject(newStatus);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This code works fine but i want to also set *StatusType* of the status entity. All possible status types are already included in the *StatusType* table. I don't want to create new statuses only create a reference.

I figured i should use something like :

```
status.StatusTypes == "new";
```

### Update 22-04-2012 13:31

The example is simplified and spans multiple projects within a solution. Because of this i prefer not to use  code within the create section  (e.g. demoEntities).I do however know the PK of the status i need to reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that your status type already exists  you also must now its primary key. Once you have a primary key value you can use this approach:

```
var newStatus = new Status {
    StatusId = status.Id,
    UserId = user.Id,
    Text = status.text,
    CreateDate = DateTime.Now
};

// Just dummy object for existing status type
var existingStatusType = new StatusType {
    Id = existingStatusTypeId
};

// Persist need status to database
using (var db = new demoEntities())
{
    db.Statuses.AddObject(newStatus);
    // First let EF know that the status type already exists
    // Attaching prior to making relation is important!
    db.StatusTypes.Attach(existingStatusType);
    // Now make relation between new and existing entity 
    newStatus.StatusTypes.Add(existingStatusType);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you don't want to create relation inside of the persistence code you must use little bit different approach.

```
var newStatus = new Status {
    StatusId = status.Id,
    UserId = user.Id,
    Text = status.text,
    CreateDate = DateTime.Now
};

// Just dummy object for existing status type
var existingStatusType = new StatusType {
    Id = existingStatusTypeId
};

newStatus.StatusTypes.Add(existingStatusType);

// Persist need status to database
using (var db = new demoEntities())
{
    // This will add both newStatus and existingStatusType as new entities
    db.Statuses.AddObject(newStatus);
    // You must fix it to make sure that existingStatusType is not inserted 
    // to database again
    status.StatusTypes.ForEach(st =>
        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(st, EntityState.Unchanged));
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: i prefer the second option because i simplified the example and in the solution it spans multiple projects. The seconds options does not seem to work because the 'status.StatusTypes' does not support a ForEach.

Comment: @Frank try `status.StatusTypes.ToList().ForEach(...)`

Comment: @Manatherin, the ToList() option works but now it is complaining that it can't resolve 'context' from the context.Entry(st).State . Doesn't this has to do with the fact that i'm using POCO objects?

Comment: `ForEach` was mostly shortcut to shorten the example - I expected that you will most probably not use `List` as a type. You can of course rewrite it as normal `foreach` statement. The `context` is my typo - it should be `db`. I will correct my answer.

Comment: I changed the it to: status.StatusTypes.ToList().ForEach(st => db.Entry(st).State = EntityState.Unchanged); but the context does not support '.Entry' what am i missing here?

Comment: I see, you are not using DbContext API. I updated the answer for ObjectContext API.