# EntityFramework many-to-many relationship bug or weird design

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many

I want to create a chat system, which has a free and a paid chats. Paid chat differs from a free one only with one property ("Price"). So paid chat inherits a free chat and adds one property to it. Also I don't want to have Paid chats with unset price. So I create a custom public constructor and leave private default constructor (so EF will be able to materialize paid chat instance).

Here is the code:

```
namespace EfTest
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Diagnostics;

    public class User
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Chat> Chats { get; set; }
    }

    public class Chat
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }

        public Chat()
        {
            this.Users = new List<User>();
        }
    }

    public class PaidChat : Chat
    {
        public int Price { get; set; }

        /* PRIVATE MODIFICATOR CAUSES THE ISSUE */
        private PaidChat() { }

        public PaidChat(int price)
        {
            Price = price;
        }
    }

    public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Chat> Chats { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Members { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<PaidChat>().ToTable("PaidChat");
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            const string ChatId = "1";

            using (var dbContext = new TestContext())
            {
                var user1 = new User { Id = "1" };
                var user2 = new User { Id = "2" };
                dbContext.Members.AddOrUpdate(m => m.Id, user1, user2);

                var paidChat = new PaidChat(50) { Id = ChatId };
                paidChat.Users.AddRange(new[] { user1, user2 });
                dbContext.Chats.AddOrUpdate(c => c.Id, paidChat);

                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var dbContext = new TestContext())
            {
                var queryResult = (from chat in dbContext.Chats
                                   where chat.Id == ChatId
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       Chat = chat,
                                       Users = chat.Users
                                   }).Single();

                Debug.Assert(queryResult.Users.Count == 2);
                Debug.Assert(queryResult.Chat.Users.Count == 2);    // !!! HERE WE HAVE A PROBLEM !!!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And private default ctor of PaidChat prevents EF to pick-up Users refecences.

Even though a proper amount of users is retrieved from DB:

```
Debug.Assert(queryResult.Users.Count == 2);
```

I can't access them from a chat instance:

```
Debug.Assert(queryResult.Chat.Users.Count == 2);    // !!! HERE WE HAVE A PROBLEM !!!
```

The issue I have with EF 5.0 and EF 6.0.2.

Is it a bug? Or maybe there is some reason why EF team implemented it that way?

Any explanation will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using lazy loading like in your case, Entity Framework creates a dynamic proxy class at runtime, which will derive from your entity type.

The proxy will override the navigation properties of the entity, and add some logic to make lazy loading possible. Thats why the navigation properties have to be declared as virtual.

All the requirements to make lazy loading work can be [found on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057.aspx).

As you can see, a private constructor will not work, so lazy loading will be disabled for that class.

The fix is to make the constructor `protected` instead, so only subclasses (the dynamic proxy) can call it.

```
public class PaidChat : Chat
{
    public int Price { get; set; }

    /* PROTECTED VISIBILITY FIXES THE ISSUE */
    protected PaidChat() { }

    public PaidChat(int price)
    {
        Price = price;
    }
}
```

Comment: Peter, thanks for your answer. And I'm surprised that "Relationship fix-up" (term from [msdn blog](http://tinyurl.com/qy3kl5w)) or "identity resolution" (term from  [StackOverflow](http://tinyurl.com/pwacn7v)) don't work here. I checked in MSSQL profiller and can confirm, that having protected or public ctor fixes the issue by means of Lazy Loading (a new query is issued when I try to access Users from chat instance). So then the question should be "Is reference resolution possible for Many-to-Many relationships"?

Comment: After thinking a little I guess I can give the answer myself. Relation fix-up can't be done on the client (like one-to-many case) as client doesn't have enough information for that (link table entries are not being matearized on the client side).

Comment: Then another question arises: how to do Many-To-Many reference conditional include? Solution from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331616/entity-framework-code-first-many-to-many-include-conditional) gives a hint about how to get Users but if I put Users into a Chat instace I have new references which are marked as Added in Object state manager and futher SaveChanges() fails. For now for that problem I use fix proposed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266827/creating-many-2-many-reference-with-ef) but it seems to be a not trivial solution for such a simple task.

Comment: @davidoff Isn't your original question about why lazy loading doesn't work? Doesn't my answer help with that problem? The links you provide in the comments are about eager loading with `Include` it seems. You should probably post a new question about that.

Answer (score 1):

*Note that I have voted up Peter´s answer because I believe it is the right answer to your first question. My answer only applies to your second question and to the intent of your code snippet:*

In order to keep track of many-to-many associations the context requires additional data from the link table that is not included in the entities themselves. While a query with Include() will retrieve such additional data and put it the context, a simple projection of entities and navigation properties will not.

Once you do a projection as in your example, you could drill down to the ObjectContext API and use something like RelatedEnd.Attach to reflect associations in the in-memory graph that already exist in the database, avoiding the associations from beign marked as added. However I would argue that when you need the level of control to load filtered subsets of a many to many associations, there might be other, more practical solutions:

1. Start the query on the other side and use include: e.g. in your case, rather than loading the chats and include the users, try querying for only the users you are interested in (you could even use a filter that refers to the chats in which the user is participating in the where clause if that is what you need) and then load all the chats associated with those users using a simple include.
2. Replace the many-to-many association with a real entity: such entity would represents the participation of a user in a chat, e.g. UserInChat. This might require writing adding additional code to manage the new entity but will give you maximum control to remove, add and query for the associations at any time.

Comment: Thanks, Divega. You confirmed my wild guess and now I'm sure I do everything correctly. Hope your answer will be useful for others. Voting up!